# Increase variable in column name Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have those columns in my database table :

value_day_1 | value_day_2| value_day_3 |......|value_day_36

I'm trying to display each value in a view using a for loop

```
@for ($n=1;$n<37;n++)
     {{ $day->value_day_? }}
@endfor
```

How can i replace the ? by $n ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution would be

```
@foreach(range(1,37) as $n)
    @php($column = 'value_day_' . $n;)
    {{ $day->$column }}
@endforeach
```

I prefer to use range instead of the `for` syntax but it is not neccessary for your problem

Answer (score 1):

```
@for ($n=1;$n<37;n++) 
    $d='value_day_'.$n;
   {{ $day->$d }}
@endfor
```

Just assign to a new variable before

Answer (score 1):

You can do this easily inline:

```
$day->{'value_day_'. $n}
```